# How to avoid Error 1242 when using LIKE with a subquery with multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have two tables. I want to find the rows from the first table that have a string in one column containing two concatenated strings that appear in some row in the second table. When I tried to write a query for this, it gave error 1242 because the subquery has multiple rows:

```
SELECT items_info.id
FROM items_info
WHERE UPPER(items_info.note) LIKE CONCAT('%',
(
    SELECT CONCAT(prefix,code)
    FROM users
    WHERE last4 IS NOT NULL
 ),'%')
```

The subquery should return `tabe1324` and `kls889` and the outer query should just display the id `1`. `ufa132` is not matched in the subquery since the `last4` column is null for the user with that code and prefix.

Perhaps using NOT LIKE with a subquery is the wrong solution? How can I get the desired result without running into this error?

Here are my tables with sample data.

Table `items_info`:

```
 id    note
  1    Code: tabe1324
  2    Used: ufa132
  3    Opened: ufa132
```

Table `users`:

```
 id    fname     lname     last4    code     prefix
  1     Jon       Doe      1234     1324      tabe
  2     Jim       Smith    NULL     132       ufa
  3     Donald    Brown    5881     889       kls
```

Comment: The subquery returns multiple rows, which causes it to fail. My example data didn't show this properly (2 NULLS, 1 not null), so I edited it accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT items_info.id
FROM items_info
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM users 
    WHERE 
        items_info.note LIKE CONCAT('%',prefix,code,'%') 
        AND last4 IS NULL
)
```

Result:

```
id
1
```

Comment: This seems to return all the rows. I did edit the data a little to make what I'm trying to do a little more clear. [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7bb60/1)

Comment: @SlackerZeitgeist, I've updated my answer. Check it now.

Comment: When I try this in the SQLFiddle, I get no rows returned. I recently edited my question with a little explanation of what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to get the opposite of your result. I would want `1` returned.

Comment: @SlackerZeitgeist, I see you updated your question and wrote that correct result would be `1`, bo this disagrees with your own code and I was basing my code on your code. Please, clarify what EXACTLY do you want to select from DB. Express this in words, not in query.

Comment: I see what you mean about my code. It should be `LIKE` not `NOT LIKE`. Sorry for the error.

I am trying to return the rows in `items_info` where the string in the note field only matches combinations of prefix and code for users that do not have a NULL in the last4 column. Does that make sense?

Comment: @SlackerZeitgeist, OK, I've updated my code again. Now it returns ids of those items for whom there is no prefix and code of user with NULL in `last4`.